# Как импортировать txt файл с заданными параметрами разделителя в google spreadsheet с помощью скрипта?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, импорт

Нужно импортировать txt файл
[image: Оригинал]
в google spreadsheets чтобы получилось так(Тип разделителя: Автоматический)
[image: Конечный результат]

Есть скрипт который только импортирует но не задает настройки

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
   var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("programs-list.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Import');
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);  
}
```

Как добавить настройки импорта

> Тип Разделителя: Автоматически
>
> Преобразование текста в числа и даты: Нет

Answer (score 0):

> Преобразование текста в числа и даты: Нет

setNumberFormat("@") устанавливает в диапазоне ячеек формат "Обычный текст", поэтому преобразование текста в число и дату не происходит. [@ - Inserts the raw text for the cell, if the cell has text input](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns)

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var id = "Id";
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("20170508_csv_excel.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('Import');
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData).setNumberFormat("@");  
}
```

Comment: а можно чуть лучше описать и пояснить Ваще решение?

Comment: @МихаилРебров setNumberFormat("@") устанавливает в диапазоне ячеек формат "Обычный текст", поэтому преобразование текста в числ и дату не происходит. [@ - Inserts the raw text for the cell, if the cell has text input](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns)